# Correct path to run python script with php from cgi-bin folder

Tags: php, python, cgi-bin

I want to run python script 'test.py' from my cgi-bin directory on my webserver.  the cgi-bin directory is at 'www/cgi-bin/'.  The python scrip is in that directory. The php code I'm executing is at 'www/html/website/index.php'.

what is the correct path that goes here ------> exec('path');

TYVM

edit: 
My python script has been chmod +x'd and is executable (I have tested)

Comment: Why do you want to run your Python CGI script via PHP? This is a *very* unorthodox thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the PHP script is in the same directory as the "www" directory.

```
<?
    exec('./www/cgi-bin/test.py'); 
?>
```

or without chmoding, you can run it through Python

```
<?
    exec('python ./www/cgi-bin/test.py'); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi I tried both of these solutions posted and neither of them work... here is the source code I'm using for my python script.

`code 
#! /usr/bin/python
f=open("./testtesttest", 'w')
f.write("testing testing 1 2 3")
f.close()`
This is simply for testing purposes..

Comment: @user583507 Where is your PHP script in the file system? do "pwd" command in the linux command line.

Comment: Its in /var/www/cgi-bin while the php website's absolute path is /var/www/html/website/index.php

Comment: @user583507 what is the absolute path to the python script? Why are you giving me the absolute path to your website? I don't understand the point, so explain. I'm aware of two scripts, the PHP script in /var/www/cgi-bin and the python script. (please answer all my questions for a quick answer)

Comment: what is the absolute path to the python script? /var/www/cgi-bin/test.py

Why are you giving me the absolute path to your website? The php code is executing in index.php NOT on a script in cgi-bin

I never said there was a php script in cgi-bin....there is a PYTHON script there.  Since I'm very new to php I can't really comment on if index.php is a script of not....but It is what creates my webpages.  I have several other helper .php files that deal with some log parsing etc. etc. (I don't need help with those)

thanks a lot for sticking with me here

Comment: So use `exec('python /var/www/cgi-bin/test.py');` or `exec('/var/www/cgi-bin/test.py');` in your index.php script. If neither of those work, then go to the command line and type in `python /var/www/cgi-bin/test.py` and let me know what it says after you type that.

Comment: Ha....no...It didn't work...There are a lot of possible reasons why it might not work on this server.....Thank you anyways I'm going to admit defeat and just write it in php (I think it's about time I learn anyways).

Comment: @user583507 well, upvote me and give me my points. I can't help it that your server is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is executing in the `www/html/website/` directory then. You need to go up two directories (arriving in the `www/` directory), then go down to the `cgi-bin/` subdirectory. So this should work:

```
exec('../../cgi-bin/test.py');
```

Note that this is relying on the current work directory being the PHP script directory. This might not always be the case, particularly if something in the PHP script changes the current work directory explicitly or simply if this PHP script is included from a different script. So it is better to use absolute paths (e.g. put the absolute path of the base directory into a config file).